# Sort images based on comparing a fraction of their pixels in a region with a folder of images and move them into seperate folders

Tags: python, image, sorting, pixel, detection

this is [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbbt9.jpg)
this is [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TWiw.jpg)
now, i want the program to basically take this part of the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Oj9.jpg) (**Note - It's important the part will be at the bottom left of an image)**

and compare it to the rest of the images, if a match has been found, move the matching files into the same folder, if an image isn't matched it goes to the next one and checks for match, when it finished going through everything, it will go to the first unmatched image and take a part from it, just like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Oj9.jpg) , and do the whole process again, but into a new, seperate folder.

the results should be a folder with multiple folders of all the pictures orginized, where every folder has a similar part in every image in the folder.

I've tried making a macro for it but after 20 tries I gave up, maybe the macro program bottle-necked me but I don't know any other way to do it except coding which im bad at.
( macro - [macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJzhO.png) )

I only know how to code in python and only beginner stuff so I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Not sure how you will find a cube in a flat 2-D image? Not sure how anyone can help without seeing what your images look like? What OS are you running?

Comment: not an actual cube, like a region of an image, for example, from pixel (0,0) to (500,500) or something like that, but only from the bottom left

Comment: I'm running windows 10 OS,
for example, this is image 1 - https://gyazo.com/66d1d86f4d5f264fc7ccdd9aca379019
this is image 2 -
https://gyazo.com/3d73afeef6d1ad513fa29b3a27e39cab
now, i want the program to basically take this part of the image -
https://gyazo.com/7a69371f5889ae9573c025581a05db92
and compare it to the rest of the images, if found, move the files into the same folder, if not, go to to the next image and do it again

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and put all the new images and information in there where it's nicely formatted, easy to read and doesn't require folk to scrabble through comments. Thank you.

Comment: reedited everything, sorry about the mess earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomand using skimage.
You can easily compare two images if you load them as an array and then define the pixels that you want to check:

```
from skimage import io

testimage = io.imread("test.png")
testimage2 = io.imread("test2.png")
sameImg = True

for y in range(1200,1400):
   for x in range(0,200):
       if testimage[y][x][0] != testimage2[y][x][0]:
           sameImg = False

print(sameImg)
```

Then you can move them with os

```
os.rename("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
```

put it in a loop and your done

Comment: The whole point of `skimage` is to use Numpy arrays, and to vectorize in order to avoid `for` loops... which are very slow.